# Vue conditional polling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
var page = new Vue({
    el: '#content-page',
    data: {
        token: null
    },

    methods: {},
    mounted: function () {
        //get token object from API
    }
});
```

The token has a property `syncStatus` that can be `inProgress` or `completed`. I want a conditional polling that will keep calling the API until the syncStatus gets the value completed.

I could make something like this:

```
var page = new Vue({
    el: '#content-page',
    data: {
        token: null
    },

    methods: {
        //Method-get-token
        //In axios.then if syncStatus is inProgress call this method again
    },
    mounted: function () {
        //get token object from API
        //if syncStatus is inProgress call method-get-token
    }
});
```

But im thinking there must be some nicer way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there is no good reason for polling at maximum speed - you should put a delay between AJAX calls (e.g. with `setTimeout()`)

Comment: Yes there will be a delay, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: There are only 3 ways to schedule something in JavaScript (if we exclude the high-precision timers in Web Audio API) - setTimeout, setInterval and RequestAnimationFrame. For your usecase `setTimeout` is the optimal choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a store

You can add a data property to hold the value of `syncStatus` then in the mounted function call the api conditionally to keep checking for the value to change.
Then add a watcher to do magic when the value of `syncStatus` changes

Something along the lines of this

```js
data() {
  return {
    syncStatus: 'notStarted' //you should think of having a default value to this
  }
},
mounted() {
  window.setInterval(()=>{
    //call the api conditionally
    if (syncStatus === 'inProgress'){
      //call the api
    }
  },MilliSeconds)
},
watch: {
  syncStatus: function(newValue) {
    //do magic when the value changes
  }
}
```